# How do I prove that there are no retraction from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to$A$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, retraction

I'm interested  in showing that there are no retractions $r:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow A$ where $A\subset \Bbb{R}^3$ such that $A$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

My idea is by contradiction.
So when we assume that there exists $r$ as above then we can consider $$r_*:\Pi_1(\Bbb{R}^3)\rightarrow \Pi_1(A)$$ And since $r$ is a retract, $r_*$ is a surjection. Therefore we have a surjection between $\Pi_1(\Bbb{R}^3)$ and $\Pi_1(S^1)=\Bbb{Z}$. But now since $\Bbb{R}^3$ is starshaped $\Pi_1(\Bbb{R}^3)=\{e\}$, so trivial. But this gives us a contradiction.

Does this works?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What kind of homomorphism does a retraction induce at the level of fundamental groups?

Comment: we never had only a retraction in combination with fundamental group we always had deformation retract, and this is more detailled right? Or does it also work with a retract

Comment: Sorry I don't really see when we use retraction and when deformation retraction therefore I'm a bit confused

Comment: Since $A$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$ your problem is equivalent to find a rectraction $r:\mathbb{R}^3\to S^1$, from this, probably the easiest idea is to use fundamental groups, but there might be some more difficult solutions.

Comment: so but is it here a retraction or a deformation rectraction because we had different definitions and we only used fundamental groups in combination with deformation retraction, is this a problem and if no why?

Comment: If $f: X\to Y$ is a continuous map between two topological spaces, do you know how to construct (using $f$ of course) a map on fundamental groups : $\pi_1(X)\to \pi_1(Y)$?

Comment: So I mean couldn't I define $$\Pi_1(X)\rightarrow \Pi_1(Y);\,\,\,[\sigma]\mapsto [f\circ \sigma]$$ or is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, so it doesnt matter if $f$ is retract or deformation retract.

Comment: But then why do we use deformation retract?

Comment: I added a possible solution above could you take a look at it if this works?

Comment: That's perfect.

Comment: Your proof is absolutely correct. The problem with questions like this is that they will most certainly remain open forever (in the sense that you will not get a formal answer which could only a simple "yes" in the present case).

Comment: ah okey so I should close it now?

Comment: @aprozz In my opinion yes.